Nvidia Physx libraries not linking properly?
I'm trying to install physx in visual studio 2022. I've installed it using vcpkg, using these commands:
vcpkg integrate install, vcpkg install physx

And I tried to include
#include <PxPhysicsAPI.h>

in Visual Studio but it gives me this error:
Cannot open source file "geometry/PxCustomGeometry" in file: PxCustomGeometryExt.h.

And 2 more errors with cannot open source file. I am failing to understand why this happening. My include directories are
D:\vcpkg\microsoft-vcpkg-a34c873\installed\x64-windows\include\physx;C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\SlugEngine\Libraries\include;$(IncludePath)

And my additional dependencies are glfw3.lib;opengl32.lib;
I tried to reinstall physx but it still gave me the same error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Note that the port has been updated several times from this question, I recommend trying again with the new port
